# Tensorflow eye function

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use the `tf.linalg.eye` function in TensorFlow to create a identity matrix, but I am having trouble understanding how to use the num_rows and num_columns arguments. Can someone explain how these arguments are used to determine the size of the identity matrix, and provide an example of how to use `tf.linalg.eye` to create a 3x3 identity matrix?

I need clarificationon how to use the `num_rows` and `num_columns` arguments to determine the size of the identity matrix, and to provide an example of how to create a 3x3 identity matrix using the `tf.linalg.eye` function.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/eye there is a quite clear example in the docs, for 3x3 you don't need the rows and cols, just `tf.eye(3)`